# Tensorflow slim load data (images, signal, "kaggle format")

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow slim but I am stuck at the beggining which is how to load the data. In fact, I find only one way on the internet : TFrecord. First, I am wondering if this format can be used for all types of data (images, signals, etc) and second if there is another way to load data (for example in keras we can load them using numpy and create some mini batch) ?